# How to click a link/bottom and let shiny automatically fill the textbox with demo text?

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app, which requires a demo button. The use need to type in a text or click a drop-off menu to select one option before precede. An example would be this webpage: http://wgpa.systems-genetics.net/basic

In this website, you can see under Step 1 they have "or try an example: Epi4K or Cardiac muscle contraction pathway". When you click on the link it inserts example data.

I want do the similar function in my shiny app

Comment: I don't understand how to be specific or on-topic for a concept question. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People are going to vote to close your question because your question is not specific enough. It would be much better if you provided a concrete example -- a simple app that you can show us an example of the button you want to press and the fields that should be filled.

To answer your question - yes, it's very easy to do with Shiny. You would just use the `updateSomething()` functions (there are many different update functions in shiny, one for each input type). Here's an example to get you started:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "Name"),
  numericInput("age", "Age", 20),
  actionButton("demo", "Fill in fields with demo")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$demo, {
    updateTextInput(session, "text", value = "Joe")
    updateNumericInput(session, "age", value = "30")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Dean, I seriously don't understand how to be more specific, it's a concept question, and I feel it's hard to ask question like this. Haha, thank you so much.

Comment: Basically if you take my code, remove the two "update" functions, and replace them with a comment saying "# what do I put in here?", that would be what people here expected.  To see actual code and a specific place you need help.